# Visually distinguish auto-generated files?

Tags: php, phpstorm, code-generation

We have a bunch of files that are auto-generated based on the database model. I have had some facepalm experiences because I modified some code, only to find out my modifications where overwritten because I'd not noticed that my changes were in those generated files.

So, I modified our generator to include a "do not modify" comment in the file header. This helps! Although, when tracing method calls, it's easy to end up in the middle of one of these files, and you wouldn't necessarily know unless you scrolled to the top to check for the header. That is awkward (and error-prone).

Is there any way to mark these files, in a similar way that "External Libraries" are marked, so it's clear from styling that these files should be read-only?

(I originally asked this in Software Engineering, but gnat asked me to move it.)

Comment: How about after generating, making them `read-only`? Chmod them to `r-xr-x-r-x`?

Comment: Or `640` assuming the web server (the file owner if PHP it created it) and the user editing the files are not one and the same - they shouldn't be; that way you don't have to juggle permissions each time the file is recreated.

Comment: If question is "What PhpStorm can do here" .. then I suggest to look at **Scopes** and **File Colors**. If such files are located inside specific folder or have some another unique part of the file name ... then you may create custom Scope that would list only such files. Then just use File Colors functionality (add your Scope there) and assign unique color -- now such files will have  that color as editor tab background (not editor itself, just editor tab) as well as background in Project View (optional; can be turned on/off for ALL scopes)

Comment: @motanelu A good suggestion, but (a) sometimes it's useful to be able to tinker around a bit; and (b) some immediate visual hint would be preferable.

Comment: @LazyOne, that works beautifully! Quick, go make your comment an answer, and you shall receive imaginary internet points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PhpStorm side you can use **Scopes** and **File Colors** functionality.

1. Create custom [Scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/scopes.html) that would list only such files (will be easier if such files are located in specific folders or have some unique part in file name .. otherwise you will have to point to individual files).
2. Use [File Colors](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/file-colors.html) functionality (add your Scope there) and assign unique color.

Now such files will have that color as editor tab background (*not editor itself, just editor tab*) as well as background in Project View/different search and other file-related popups (optional; can be turned on/off but it will do that for ALL scopes).

This whole procedure/idea has even got own help page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html?search=scope

Comment: This was _exactly_ what I was looking for. PhpStorm has soo many options to customize, I knew there had to be something.